# Why do towels go crispy when air-dried but not in the tumble-dryer; when other materials don't have this effect so noticeably?

Tags: everyday-life, material-science, elasticity

Our tumble dryer recently broke, so we've resorted to hanging our clothes on banisters etc.

I've noticed that, when air-dried, towels (as well as cotton "muslin" cloths) go crispy, kind of hard, rough when dry.

Is it purely because the tumble dryer is constantly moving the items? That would explain why they go soft in a tumble-dryer, but not why they go hard in air. What's the physics behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cotton fibers dry, they have a slight tendency to bond together, making the cloth containing them slightly stiff. A tumble dryer mashes up the cloth, breaking those weak bonds as fast as they form, whereas line-drying them does not. This is why cotton cloth gets crispy on the line and not in the dryer.